# Windows sometimes puts msi path record in \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\. How to disable that option?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installer

I have a problem with msi installer.
Some users have problem with updating my application via msi because they got error that msi cannot find remote path.
I know how to fix it. All i need to do is remove record from \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\ and it fixes the problem.

But i don't know how it happens that some users have record there and how to block windows from putting it there.

Including screen of error for visualization , but it's in polish :)[image]

Comment: Can you show the data in the registry so we can see what is up? It sounds strange. Are you installing to a network path?

Comment: What custom actions do you have in this MSI? What are they doing?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul I can't show you right know, because i don't have any screen of it, but resolution i found on microsoft page https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/971187
In Custom actions i have mostly saving some config and deleting directories on delete.